# Recreating iOS 7 Calendar UIView Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uianimation

Everybody knows the brand-new awesome animation inside iOS 7 Calendar app. You can see them in this short video: http://vimeo.com/69247779

I would recreating something like that creating a "modal" rectangle that appear when the user taps on a `UIButton`. When the user taps on this button the app should move an `UIView` (actually inside an `UITableViewCell`) and move it within this rectangle, BUT the original `UIView` should stay in the same place. It needs to duplicate itself, something alike.

I've created a simple image explaining the concept.

[image]

How to implement something like this?

Answer (score 0):

i might suggest you to create another UIView. Do not add it to the main view yet.

now on the view that you're currently working on,

```
[UIView transitionWithView: self.view duration: 0.5 options: UIViewAnimationOptionsCurveEaseOut animations:^{
[self.view addSubView:createdView]; } completion:nil];
```

Hope this works, if you haven't already implemented. I'm a beginner, excuse me if there's any mistake.

Answer (score -1):

I assume we're looking for something similar :-)
[How to display datepicker like that in iOS 7 calendar UIDatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447871/how-to-display-datepicker-like-that-in-ios-7-calendar-uidatepicker) , apologies if its not. @bobnoble has pointed to exact solution. I'm trying to achieve it but I'm new to iOS so bit stuck.
Found another link with sample code :-) [iOS 7 - How to display a date picker in place in a table view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973573/ios7-how-to-display-a-date-picker-in-place-in-a-table-view)