# IOS - UIDateView to UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have implemented a UIDatePicker IOS7 View into a static tableview with the help of  - [iOS 7 - How to display a date picker in place in a table view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973573/ios7-how-to-display-a-date-picker-in-place-in-a-table-view)

All works great- my only issue now is how to display the result in my UITextField once a date has been selected?  Sounds like it should be a simple thing - but as its a static field I'm not sure how to access the date property once a selection is made or which method to apply the code to!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good pattern to follow would be sending the date selected in the `UIDatePicker` back to the `UIViewController` that is handling the `UITableView` via delegation. This can be done by assigning an `IBAction` to the `valueChanged:` control event of the date picker.

Once you have obtained the `NSDate`, you can transform it into text with the format of your choosing using an `NSDateFormatter`