# How to add custom cell into a static tableview built by storyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I use storyboard to build a tableview, and set Content to static, I design some custom cells in the tableview, each one were different, and what I want is, when I click 3rd cell, a new custom cell with a datePicker in it will be inserted next to 3rd cell, just like create a new event in iPhone calendar, but I tried many ways, all failed.

Who has experience can share with me, or maybe I need consider another way? Kindly advise me, thanks~

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us screenshots and/or code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has some sample code in place for this in [DateCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008866)

You can also check some related discussion in [iOS 7 - How to display a date picker in place in a table view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973573/ios-7-how-to-display-a-date-picker-in-place-in-a-table-view)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sections in table view for this. Initially hide the table view with the
date picker cell. On the 3rd cell click reload the table view with the required cell using the data or just unhide the view.