# UIDatePickerView In Popup in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5

Trying to show `UIDatePickerView` as `dialog box` like it shows in `Android`. I tried to add it on `UIAlertView` but not able to add.

Anyone tried this?

Comment: If you click ok button in alertbox does need to open datePicker?

Comment: No, I have button on my screen. On tap of that button I need UIDatePicker as popup like UIAlertView where I can select date. Got my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AddSubview is not available in `UIAlertView` in iOS7

The `UIAlertView` class is intended to be used as-it-is and does not support subclassing. 
The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

You should use `UIAlertViewcontoller`. Here is the code :

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
[picker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
[alertController.view addSubview:picker];
[alertController addAction:({
UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
NSLog(@"OK");
NSLog(@"%@",picker.date);
}];
action;
})];
UIPopoverPresentationController *popoverController = alertController.popoverPresentationController;
popoverController.sourceView = sender;
popoverController.sourceRect = [sender bounds];
[self presentViewController:alertController  animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope this will help you....

Answer (score 0):

In button action I set the datePicker

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
  UIDatePicker *datepicker;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController         



-(IBAction) showDatePicker:(id)sender
{
  UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
  datepicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];  
  [datepicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime];
  [datepicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
  [datepicker addTarget:self action:@selector(getPickerValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

  [alertController addAction:({
    UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        NSLog(@"The selected or picked datePicker value is - %@",datepicker.date);
        txtfldGetDatePickerValue.text = [self getStringDateFromDate:datepicker.date];
    }];
    action;
})];

[alertController.view addSubview:datepicker];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)getPickerValue:(UIDatePicker *)pickerDate
{
  txtfldGetDatePickerValue.text = [self getStringDateFromDate:pickerDate.date];
}

-(NSString *)getStringDateFromDate:(NSDate *)pickerDate
{
  NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
  return [formatter stringFromDate:pickerDate];
}
```

I tried many solutions and I got the output finally.Since I did not give the answer properly I wanted to give best answer for your question.I googled so many answer.Even I created sample project to achieve this.I did not use action sheet and popoverpresentration view controller.Simply I used the coding with UIAlertViewController.

[UIDatePicker to action sheet was discouraged by Apple all along](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26340932/how-to-add-uidatepicker-in-uialertcontroller-in-ios8)

Comment: It will show UIDatepicker on specific location not like popup.

Comment: Do you need to implement this for iPhone or iPAd?

Comment: in iPhone. iPad provides UIPopoverViewController for this.

Answer (score 0):

This will work.. check out the code.This will work in ios7 and above

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Date" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
   UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, alert.bounds.size.height, 320, 216)];
[alert addSubview:picker];
alert.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320 + 20, alert.bounds.size.height + 216 + 20);
[alert setValue:picker forKey:@"accessoryView"];
[alert show];
```

Answer (score 0):

For Showing Popover in Phone Just Make Category of UIPopoverController
Code :

```
//  UIPopoverController+iPhone.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIPopoverController (iPhone)
+ (BOOL)_popoversDisabled;
@end
//  UIPopoverController+iPhone.m


#import "UIPopoverController+iPhone.h"

@implementation UIPopoverController (iPhone)
+ (BOOL)_popoversDisabled {
    return NO;
}
@end
```

This Will Help you Surely.

Comment: @surendrasheoran Just Import Category Where you wanna use