# origin of view inside the tableview cell shows wrong frame in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have created the app with the following code. In which when i press the button the date picker should load in corresponding row. But the datepicker is always loading in the first row. Can anyone help me to do this?

My code as follows:

```
- (void)datePickerButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
if(self.datePicker == nil)
{
    self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    [self.datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerDateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
NSMutableArray *items = [self.toolbar.items mutableCopy];
[items removeObjectAtIndex:2];
[items addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(datePickerDone:)]];
[self.toolbar setItems:items animated:YES];

CGPoint swipepoint = sender.center;
CGPoint rootViewPoint = [sender.superview convertPoint:swipepoint toView:self.goalDetailsTableview];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.goalDetailsTableview indexPathForRowAtPoint:rootViewPoint];
NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
GoalDetailsTableViewCell *cell = [self.goalDetailsTableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;

CGRect pickerRect = CGRectMake(cell.actionCardReminder.frame.origin.x, cell.actionCardReminder.frame.origin.y, 304, 204);
NSLog(@"%f  %f", cell.actionCardReminder.frame.origin.x, cell.actionCardReminder.frame.origin.y);
self.datePicker.frame = pickerRect;
self.datePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.datePicker.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

[self.goalDetailsTableview addSubview:self.datePicker];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do your two logs show?

Comment: Try this `pickerRect.origin.y = rootViewPoint.y` and check

Comment: @rdelmar - my log shows x origin at 8 and y origin as 18 and datepicker shows at first cell only but my i want the same origin for selected cell

Comment: You can check it once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973573/ios-7-how-to-display-a-date-picker-in-place-in-a-table-view

Comment: @Akhilrajtr - Actually it also shows datepicker in first row only..

Comment: @Balaji are you getting correct `GoalDetailsTableViewCell *cell` ?

Comment: @Akhilrajtr - It works fine. Actually we have to made change in origin y.. Thank u..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue may due to `y` position of `pickerRect`.

Try this

```
CGRect pickerRect = CGRectMake(cell.actionCardReminder.frame.origin.x, rootViewPoint.y, 304, 204);
```

In your code `cell.actionCardReminder.frame` refer to the frame inside the `cell`. So the `y` position will also be a point inside `cell` frame. So it will always show from first row. Updating `y` will solve the issue.